# Javascript html table cell edit not happening properly

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an html table with 4 columns. In that table, one of the columns is an editable one (with edit button).

When I click on the edit button it's working as expected if there is 1 record in my html table. But if I have 2 records it's not working as expected.

When I click on 2nd record edit button, it's making the first record in the table editable.

Please find my html code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function update_country() {
        if(document.getElementById("Editbtn").value == 'Edit'){
            document.getElementById("country").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("Editbtn").value = "Update";
            document.getElementById("countries").style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
    }

</script>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td id="country">Germany</td>
    <td id="countryOption">
    <select name="countries" id="countries" style="display:none;  >
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
    <option value="India">India</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
    </select>
    <input id="Editbtn" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="update_country()"> 
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>102</td>
    <td>Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td id="country">Italy</td>
    <td id="countryOption">
    <select name="countries" id="countries" style="display:none;  >
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
    <option value="India">India</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
    </select>
    <input id="Editbtn" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="update_country()"> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  
 </table>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: ` document.getElementById` will always return the first element matching the id.

Comment: 'id' should be unique, you can use a class and add the event with 'for' to each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementById` will always return the first element matching the id.

So instead you could just grab the clicked target:

```js
function update_country( e ) {
  if( e.target.value == 'Edit' ) {
    e.target.value = 'Update'
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector( '#country' ).style.display = 'none'
    e.target.parentNode.querySelector( '#countries' ).style.display = 'inline-block'
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td id="country">Germany</td>
    <td id="countryOption">
      <select id="countries" class="countries" style="display:none;">
        <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="France">France</option>
        <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
      </select>
      <input id="Editbtn" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="update_country(event)">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>102</td>
    <td>Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td id="country">Italy</td>
    <td id="countryOption">
      <select id="countries" class="countries" style="display:none;">
        <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="France">France</option>
        <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
      </select>
      <input id="Editbtn" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="update_country(event)">
    </td>
  </tr>

 </table>
```

Comment: `e.target.parentNode.getElementById is not a function` --> this error is throwing for the line  `e.target.parentNode.parentNode.getElementById( 'country' ).style.display = 'none'`

Comment: Yes I also realised this in between, just set classes instead of id's and use `getElementByClassName`. This would be better anyway since an id should be unique.

Comment: for `e.target.parentNode.getElementByClassName('country').style.display = 'none'` also am getting function not found issue.

Comment: yes it¨s `e.target.parentNode.parentNode.getelementByClassName( 'country' )`. Look at my answer I updated it a while ago.

Comment: ok, edited again the answer and used the original id's. Looks like `tr` only supports `getElementsByClassName` and not `getElementByClassName`. Now I opted for `.querySelector` which could also target a class if you wish.